# How to hide/display edit button in jqgrid for the user/Admin only?

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with edit/delete/add functionalities. I would like to display those action items only if for the users that have Admin privilages. For everybody other than Admin privileges should not see the edit/delete or add buttons in jqgrid nav bar. 
I am using PHP to authenticate users. Right now who ever logged in to the web site can do add, edit, delete actions.

here is my code for jqgrid:

```
function doOneGrid()
{ 
var data={};
data.PRODUCT = prod;
data.RELEASE=rel;

prod = $("#productCombo").val();
rel = $("#releaseCombo").val();


jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

    url:"/ProductionScheduler/controller/productcontroller.php?q=2&prod="+prod+"&rel="+rel,
    datatype: "json",
    type:"POST",
    height: 450,
colNames:['Product','Version','ProductionVersion','Status','ProductionStatus','Production','PackagingStatus','PackagingDate','SanityStatus','To_Sanity', 'STStatus','To_ST','eeQSStatus','To_eeQS','GAStatus','To_GA','Notes','Milestones'
    ],

colModel:[


    {name:'Product',index:'Product', width:150,align:"center",sorttype:"string",editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;OSV:OSV;OSB:OSB;SBC:SBC;LogManager:LogManager;Fusion for Outlook:Fusion for Outlook;Fusion for Lync/MOC:Fusion for Lync/MOC"},formoptions:{rowpos:1},editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'Version',index:'Version', width:150,align:"center",sorttype:"string",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true,editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"V8:V8;V7R1:V7R1;V7:V7;V6:V6"}},    
            {name:'ProductionVersion',index:'ProductionVersion',title:"false",editable:true, width:250,align:"center",sorttype:"string",cellattr: function () { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'}},
            {name:'Status',index:'Status', width:100,align:"center",sorttype:"string",editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Planned:Planned;Produced:Produced;In Sanity:In Sanity; In System Test:In System Test; In Field Trial:In Field Trial; In GA:In GA;TBD:TBD;N/A:N/A;Removed:Removed;Canceled:Canceled"}},  
            {name:'ProductionStatus',index:'ProductionStatus', width:100,align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;Actual:Actual;Plan:Planned"}},
            {name:'Production',index:'ProductionDate', width:100,align:"center",editable:true,sorttype:"date"},
            {name:'PackagingStatus',index:'PackagingStatus', width:100,align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;Actual:Actual;Plan:Planned"}},        
            {name:'Packaging',index:'PackagingDate', width:100,align:"center",sorttype:"date",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }},
            {name:'SanityStatus',index:'SanityStatus', width:100,align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;Actual:Actual;Plan:Planned"}},
            {name:'To_Sanity',index:'Sanity_Regression_Date', width:100, align:"center",sorttype:"date",editable:true},//jsonmap:"cell.1.value"
            {name:'STStatus',index:'STStatus', width:100,align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;Actual:Actual;Plan:Planned"}},
            {name:'To_ST',index:'ST_Date', width:100, align:"center",sorttype:"date",editable:true},//formatter:myFormatter},
            {name:'eeQSStatus',index:'eeQSStatus', width:100,align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;Actual:Actual;Plan:Planned"}},
            {name:'To_eeQS',index:'eeQS_Date', width:100, align:"center",sorttype:"date",editable:true},//formatter:myFormatter},
            {name:'GAStatus',index:'GAStatus', width:100,align:"center",hidden:true,editable:true,hidedlg: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Default:;Actual:Actual;Plan:Planned"}},
    {name:'To_GA',index:'GA_Date', width:100, align:"center",sorttype:"date",editable:true},//,formatter:myFormatter},
            {name:'Notes',index:'Notes', width:200, align:"center",sorttype:"string",editable:true,cellattr: function () { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'}},//cellattr: function () { return 'style=\"background:orange\"'}},
            {name:'Milestones',index:'Milestones', width:100, align:"center",sorttype:"string",editable:true,cellattr: function () { return 'style="white-space: normal;"'}},
    ],


    rowNum:25,
rowList:[50,100,300],
pager: '#pager',
sortname: 'ProductionVersion',
    sortorder: "desc", 
    editurl:"/ProductionScheduler/controller/action.php",
      viewrecords: true,
    autowidth: true,
   caption: "Schedule",
  onCellSelect:function(rowid,icol, cellcontent,e){

      var dataFromTheRow=jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowid);
    },


    subGrid : true, 
    subGridUrl: "/ProductionScheduler/controller/subgrid.php?q=1", 
    subGridModel: [
      { name : ['Product','Release','Field_Updated','Old_Value', 'New_Value','Update_Type','Name_Updated','Date_Created','Notes'], 

                    width : [80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80],
                    params:['Product','ProductionVersion'],
                    sortname:['DateCreated'],
                    sortorder: "asc"
                } ]


});

 jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true,defaultSearch:"cn"});
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:true,add:true,edit:true,search:true,cloneToTop:true},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. Leave the buttons in place, but, retrieve a 'permissions' value from the data returned and then use that within the add/delete/update buttons on the pager, bind a click event to determine if the user can edit/delete or show a message stating that they do not have access.
2. Add your own buttons to the pager, and set the edit/delete ones that are built in to false. Take the permissions value and then determine the display property of these buttons within loadComplete.
   Instead of getting the value from data retrieved for the grid, you could store it in a hidden field.

   `var permission = $('#hidden').val(); 
    $('#list').jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function() {
     if (permission === xxx){
       $('#edit').hide();
     }
    })
    .navButtonAdd('#list', { id: "edit", ... }

    }`